# My Website Images Don't Fit To Screen On Other Devices

Tags: html, css, image, position, cross-browser

I made a website for fun & testing but it doesn't look well on mobile as it works on desktop, especially images and specially positioned stuff got out of page. I tried

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but it still looks a way that nobody wants to see.

I'm a newbie codder please forgive my flaws :)

website: http://ersinski.epizy.com/

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1):

in your css file:

```
img {
max-width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are centering things with `left: 500px;`. It's a fixed distance from the left side that will only look centered on a specific screen size. For example on a device with a screen width of 320px(mobile) all your 'centered' elements will start 500px from the left side even if that means going beyond the device screen.

For dynamic design look into [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

And for your specific website:

1. Remove all the `left: 500px;` on 'centered' elements
2. Add `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` to your body element
3. Add `align-self: center;` to anything you wanna center horizontally.

Comment: Really but really thanks man! This is what I'm looking for days!